# Probability Mutually exclusive events 5

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Events A and B are mutually exclusive. Suppose event A occurs with probability $0.19$ and event B occurs with probability $0.72$. If A does not occur, what is the probability that B does not occur? Round your answer to at least two decimal places.

My answer is $0.09/0.81=0.11$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: I don't understand the down vote.  The OP stated his question clearly and showed his work.  What more do you want?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Well, indeed, while Jake didn't show *all* the work, the numbers are certainly correct.  It's not *too* bad as questions go.  (Better than many we see.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.   But you really should show your work instead of just magic numbers. $$\begin{split}\mathsf P(B'\mid A')&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(B'\cap A')}{\mathsf P(A')}\\[2ex] &=\dfrac{1-\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A)\require{cancel}\cancelto 0{+~\mathsf P(A\cap B)}}{1-\mathsf P(A)}\\[2ex] &= \dfrac{0.09}{0.81}\end{split}$$